# HQL left join with condition in onetoMany

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, oracle-sqldeveloper, spring-data-jpa

Appointments and shift tables with onetomany relationship .

SQL query to find all the shift details where appointment day is saturday 
Want to display all the shifts even if there are no appointments .

:

```
// this query works in sql developer
select * from TEST_SHIFTS s LEFT OUTER JOIN TEST_APPOINTMENT2 a
   ON s.SHIFT_NUMBER = a.SHIFT_ID and a.APP_DAY='Sat'
```

HQL query :

```
@Query("Select s FROM Shifts s LEFT JOIN s.appointments a with a.APP_DAY='Sat'")

@Query("Select s FROM Shifts s LEFT JOIN s.appointments a on a.APP_DAY='Sat'")

@Query("Select s FROM Shifts s LEFT JOIN s.appointments a on s.shiftId = a.shifts and a.APP_DAY='Sat'")
```

None of the above hql queries are giving the required result .

Below are the two entities used :

```
@Entity
@Table(name="TEST_APPOINTMENT2")
public class NewAppointment {

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name="Appoint_Id")
    private int appointmentId;

     @ManyToOne
     @JoinColumn(name="shiftId")
    // @JsonBackReference
     //@JsonIgnore
     private Shifts shifts;
.....    
}


@Entity
@JsonIdentityInfo(generator=ObjectIdGenerators.PropertyGenerator.class, property="shiftId",scope=Shifts.class)
@Table(name="TEST_SHIFTS")

public class Shifts {

    @Id
     @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
     @Column(name="ID")
     private int shiftId;


     @OneToMany(mappedBy="shifts" )
//   @JsonManagedReference
//   @JsonIgnore
     private List<NewAppointment> appointments;

.....

}
```

Comment: Please, try the following query: @Query("Select s FROM Shifts s LEFT JOIN s.appointments a WHERE a.APP_DAY = 'Sat'")

Comment: I tried this too , this query is only giving me the shifts in which appointments has app_day  = "Sat" .  I want all the shift with null value of appointments if the condition is not met

Comment: Then @Query("Select s FROM Shifts s LEFT JOIN s.appointments a WHERE a.APP_DAY = 'Sat' OR a IS NULL")

Comment: I tried it  , I get all the shifts but with all the appointments not which are  following the condition.

Comment: I want to display history of appointments shift wise and at a particular day . Please suggest i am stuck on this issue . Do i have to make one more table to make it possible ?? Also i want to display empty slots shift wise which is calculated by number of beds